# Sending notifications to many iphone/android in seconds

Tags: android, iphone, firebase, push-notification

We have an app that aims to send instant notifications to our users ios/android, and we want to send huge number of users and they should receive them in seconds. We're using *Firebase* and we expect to have delay when users receive notification, I want to ask what is the best strategy to send users with no delay.

1. we expect to send to 200K users at once
2. our delivery target to all users is less than 8 sec.

If anyone knows *365scores* they send notifications to million users in 3 seconds, I want to know what would be a solution for us, can *Firebase*  be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In our company we send notifications with OneSignal. It's better and cheaper when compared to Firebase, also the notifications arrive almost instantly. It has a good and user friendly API. I'm not advertising, just sharing my experience.

Comment: i second onesignal. really solid framework. Adobe has one too... forget the name, but you can google it.